# Github Action: Build-tool 33.0.0 is missing DX at /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/dx

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins, github-actions

I am trying to generate android apk using github action. My project is developed using Vue + Cordova.

I have written github workflow but I am getting below error:

> Build-tool 33.0.0 is missing DX at
> /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/dx

[image]

```
name: Build Android

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production
      - staging
      - test

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x

      - name: Install Cordova
        run: npm install -g cordova

      - name: Install Vue
        run: npm install -g @vue/cli@5.0.1

      - name: Install app dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Generate Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Add Android platform
        run : |
          cordova platform add android

      - name: Build Android Dev APK
        run: |
          cordova build android

      - name: Upload dev APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-dev
          path: platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve this by renaming d8 files to dx. Here is updated workflow..

```
name: Build Android

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production
      - staging
      - test

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x

      - name: Install Cordova
        run: npm install -g cordova

      - name: Install Vue
        run: npm install -g @vue/cli@5.0.1

      - name: Install app dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Generate Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Fixing Android Build Tool Issue
        run: |
            cd $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/33.0.0
            mv d8 dx
            cd lib
            mv d8.jar dx.jar

      - name: Add Android platform
        run : |
          cordova platform add android

      - name: Build Android Dev APK
        run: |
          cordova build android

      - name: Upload dev APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-dev
          path: platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: This also worked for me outside of a github workflow, on the cli. Boils down to the `Fixing…`  step.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite pointless using v 33 of build tools and SDK since Cordova only supports up to SDK 32 (with cordova-android 11).
Downgrade your build tools to 32. (or even 30).

Comment: I haven't specified anywhere in my code to use v33.